# My phone won't send icmp/ping unless WiiFi connected. Can this be fixed?

Tags: settings, networking, remote-access, echo

I have local terminal access and `ping` command works when WiFi connected, but not when connected via cellular service. I get same results using `ping` within other apps.

Can this be "fixed?"

Phone is Verizon, brand Samsng J7 V, software build M1AJQ.J727VVRU2BSA1

Answer (score 0):

Mobile network operaters block outbound ICMP echo sometimes, and inbound ICMP echo most of the times. You can use `nping` to use TCP or UDP for pinging if you know some open port on destination. Or you can use a third party service like https://ping.eu/ping. But be sure your endpoint is responsive to echo requests, some routers and PCs are also configured not to respond. E.g. on Linux or Android to block echo requests:

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```