# Why 'ping localhost' command in Termux returns a normal response even though there is no local web server?

Tags: linux, networking, termux

I just tried 'ping localhost'command in Termux and response was positive.
How this is possible since I don't have a local web server running.

Comment: Ping (ICMP traffic) is processed by the network stack of the OS like in any other OS.

Comment: ... and not by a web (or any other) server. Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215881/218526